# Checking uniqueness for many to many association in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create a Rails app that allows a user to input a recipe and tag it as a type of recipe. I've created a model for both "Recipe" and "Tag" and given them a many to many association. 
Right now, I'm trying to add a method that will check to see if the user's input tag name already exists in the database. If it does, I want to use that tag and if not, I want to create a new tag. That way I'll avoid duplicated tag names. (Because eventually I want users to be able to search recipes by tags, and I don't want something like "chicken" listed 10000 times).

I've been able to successfully create new tags, but the check for whether or not the tag is in the database doesn't seem to be working--every time it saves a new tag name.

Here's the method I've been trying to make work within my controller:

tag_controller.rb

```
def add_tag
  tag_name_string_from_user = params[:tag][:name]
  @tag = Tag.where(name: tag_name_string_from_user)
  if @tag.nil?
    @tag = Tag.new(name: tag_name_string_from_user)
    @tag.save
    @recipe.tags << @tag
    render 'show.html.erb'
  end
end
```

And here's the test I've been trying to write for it. I'm trying to figure out whether or not the user input is being passed on to the @tag--I have a feeling it isn't, but I'm not sure exactly how to test for that.

recipe_tag_join_spec.rb

```
it "should allow you to create a tag" do
  visit "/recipes/new"
  fill_in 'Title', :with =>'myTitle'
  fill_in 'Author', :with =>'myAuthor'
  fill_in 'Ingredients', :with =>'myIngredients'
  fill_in 'Instructions', :with =>'myInstructions'
  click_button 'Create Recipe'
  fill_in "Tag Name", :with => "string"
  expect(find_field("Tag Name").value).to eq "string"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`.nil?` will return true even if no records are returned. Use `.empty?` instead.

You might want to try the `uniqueness` validation, though. Take a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness).

Answer (score 0):

> I've been able to successfully create new tags, but the check for
>   whether or not the tag is in the database doesn't seem to be
>   working--every time it saves a new tag name.

That's not what is happening in the code.

```
 @tag = Tag.where(name: tag_name_string_from_user)
 if @tag.nil?
   @tag = Tag.new(name: tag_name_string_from_user)
   @tag.save
   @recipe.tags << @tag
   render 'show.html.erb'
 end
```

According to the code, you aren't creating any new Tag objects, since it will never pass the if statement. The nil? will always evaluate to *false*, since the where method will always return an ActiveRecordRelation object (even if it's empty).

Also see for reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where

The description starts with:

> Returns a new relation, ...

You could check your @tag for *empty?* as already suggested or check it for `present?` (which will also check it for nil?).

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is you're expecting `where` to return `nil` in some cases, but `where` *never* returns `nil`.  You *could* change your conditional as some of the other answers suggest, but you could also just *not* use `where`.

For what you're doing, `find_by` is a better choice, since it returns the first matching record (or `nil` if no matching record).  [find_by docs here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object)   Using `find_by` would cause the rest of your code to function as expected.

Going a step further, you should consider using `find_or_create_by` to further simplify your code.  In other words, you don't need to reinvent the code for creating a tag that doesn't exist or returning the tag if it does exist. [Docs here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by)

Regardless of which solution you end up using in Ruby (e.g. `where`, `find_by`, `find_or_create_by`, `valid?`, etc.), you *will* want to *also* create a unique index in your database to ensure you don't get duplicate tags.  Even the best Ruby code won't prevent a race condition whereby the same tag gets created twice at virtually the same instant.

Comment: Thanks so much! find_or_create_by worked perfectly! Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure Tag name is unique, add this `validates :name, uniqueness: true` to the Tag model. Then try to create a new tag:

```
@tag = Tag.new(name: tag_name_string_from_user)
if @tag.valid?
  @tag.save
  @recipe.tags << @tag
else
  @tag=nil
end
```

This works better because you can add code to process name string before it is validated.